# Why does my site's average position drop on weekends?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, performance

I noticed a weird patten in my GSC Performance chart - average position drops on weekends and rises back up on Mondays, peaking mostly the middle of the week.
The standard response "Well, people aren't searching that much on weekends" doesn't seem to make sense. If people aren't searching, then the number of impressions should drop, not the position. Does anyone have any ideas?

[image: Position on Weekday]

[image: Position on weekends]

EDIT: My blog is on [property taxes](https://blog.squaredeal.tax/) and the articles are mostly informative in nature. Here are some of the queries that my pages rank for:

[image: property tax related search queries]

Comment: I probably have the answer but to narrow this down:
Is this related to a business location, with opening hours?
What kind of search are they making? Is it related to a product, or business, or a knowledge query?
Are you a publisher of some sort?

Comment: @LMartin I edited my question to provide context around my content and search queries, Hope they answer your questions.

Comment: Average position has little meaning unless you are looking at a single query. Are the query terms changing on the weekend to ones that you rank lower for?